# garuma/FlyOutMenu - How to make it slide from right to left

Tags: xamarin.android, slidingmenu, android-sliding

I am using [garuma/FlyOutMenu](https://github.com/garuma/FlyOutMenu) for my project. How can have the **Hamburger button** in the right and slide the menu from **right to left** as it is shown in facebook.

Comment: I don't think you can. Why don't you use something like DrawerLayout from Support v4 or SlidingMenuSharp?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I have used [DrawerLayout](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) which is provided in the example and it is working perfectly now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We could use [DarwerLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) which is provided in the example to achieve this. I have used this and working perfectly.